# OCaml: how to use user defined types as key for Map.Make?

Tags: dictionary, ocaml

I have the following code which I intend to create a `Map` with self defined types `variable` and `location`. I understand that the key type should be ordered (some comparator function). How shall I add these rules to make this work? Also, I find the code ugly here. Do I really need the `;;` at the end of a `type` and `module`?

```
type variable = string;;
type location = int;;
module LocationMap = Map.Make(variable);;
module EnvironmentMap = Map.Make(location);;
```

**EDIT** 
This is the rest of my code:

```
type variable = Variable of string
type location = Location of int
module LocationMap = Map.Make(struct type t = variable let compare = compare end)
module EnvironmentMap = Map.Make(struct type t = variable let compare = compare end)

(*file read function*)
let read_file filename =
  let lines = ref [] in
  let chan = open_in filename in
  try
    while true do
      lines := input_line chan :: !lines
    done;
    !lines
  with End_of_file ->
    close_in chan;
    List.rev !lines
in

(*get the inputs*)
let inputs = read_file Sys.argv.(1) in
for i = 0 to List.length inputs - 1 do
  Printf.printf "%s\n" (List.nth inputs i)
done;
```

This has a syntax error. I am not sure why. 
**EDIT2**

I make this work with the following edit:

```
type variable = Variable of string
type location = Location of int
module LocationMap = Map.Make(struct type t = variable let compare = compare end)
module EnvironmentMap = Map.Make(struct type t = variable let compare = compare end)

(*file read function*)
let read_file filename =
  let lines = ref [] in
  let chan = open_in filename in
  try
    while true do
      lines := input_line chan :: !lines
    done;
    !lines
  with End_of_file ->
    close_in chan;
    List.rev !lines

(*get the inputs*)
let () = 
  let inputs = read_file Sys.argv.(1) in
  for i = 0 to List.length inputs - 1 do
    Printf.printf "%s\n" (List.nth inputs i)
  done;
```

Sorry for the long list of questions, what does `let () =` do here? Is it true that when I define a function with `let`, I do not need `in`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When applying the Map.Make functor, you need to supply a struct containing your type and a compare function:

```
module LocationMap =
    Map.Make(struct type t = variable let compare = compare end)
module EnvironmentMap =
    Map.Make(struct type t = location let compare = compare end)
```

You never need to use `;;` in compiled code. It's only required when using the toplevel, to tell it when it should evaluate what you've typed in so far.

Some people do use `;;` in compiled code, but you never need to do this and I personally never do. There is always a way to get the same effect without using `;;`.

**Update**

The `let compare = compare` binds the pre-existing OCaml function `compare` (the infamous polymorphic comparison function) to the name `compare` inside the struct. So, it creates a Map that uses polymorphic compare to do its comparisons. This is often what you want.

I created a file containing your definitions (without `;;`) and the above code, then compiled it with `ocamlc -c`. There were no syntax errors. I'm positive you don't need to use `;;`, as I've written many many thousands of lines of code without it.

Note that I'm *not* saying that if you remove `;;` from syntactically correct OCaml code, the result is always syntactically correct. There are a few idioms that only work when you use `;;`. I personally just avoid those idioms.

**Update 2**

A `let` at top level of a module is special, and doesn't have an `in`. It defines a global value of the module. OCaml treats every source file as a module (for free, as I like to say), with a name that's the same as the source file name (capitalized).

You can actually have any pattern in `let pattern = expression`. So `let () = ...` is completely normal. It just says that the expression has unit type (hence the pattern matches).

Comment: This works. But could you please tell me what does `let compare = compare end` mean? As for the `;;` issue, if I take away all the `;;`, there is a syntax error.

Comment: Does the updated code contain one of the idioms you mentioned?

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to write top-level statements (unit expressions) (not top-level `let`s), you need to use `;;` to separate the expressions from the `let`s. My solution (which is exactly what you did) is to use `let () = ...` for top-level statements.